# Version not compatible with device in Google Play Store

Tags: android, mobile, google-play, huawei-mobile-services

I have an app published in play store. However, one of friends that uses a Huawei P9 PLUS phone unable to install the app from Google Play Store with the message "Version not compatible with device"

Steps I have taken to troubleshoot this issue:

1. OS version (Phone default is 6.0 Marshmallow. The min SDK version is 14 and target is 24)
2. Confirmed that I didn't use any uses-feature in android manifest.
3. Within supported screensize
4. Apps is allowed in 100+ Country + rest of the world
5. Checked in play store developer console. Huawei P9 plus is supported.

Is there any other way for me to troubleshoot such issue.

EDIT: I just find out I'm able to install the apps on the another phone with the same model but not the current phone.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem before where I had a phone-only app but wanted to allow it to be installed on tablets as well.  So, I took care of all the requirements of adding tablet images, etc. to get it supported on tablets.  Then, it showed in the developer console that it was now supported on tablets but the tablet was still showing that it wasn't.

It only worked after I uploaded another apk.  Could that be your problem as well?

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I just find out I'm able to install the apps on the another phone with the same model but not the current phone.

Answer (score 0):

After clearing data and cache of Google Play Store app, the incompatible issue gone and I'm able to download and install the my app again.